# Global Search not working with laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Hi guys im trying to get an specific search for my proyect but it doesnt want to work, I'm using relationships this is my code 
Php:

```
public function todos_productos($empresa_id, Request $request)
{


    $empresa = Empresa::find($empresa_id);
    $productos = $empresa->productos()->with('producto_nombre', 'producto_nombre.seccion', 'producto_nombre.linea');

    return Datatables::of($productos)
        ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ($request->has('codigo')) {
                $query->where('producto_nombre.codigo', 'like', "%{$request->get('codigo')}%");
            }
        })
        ->make(true);
```

}

My js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  empresa = $('#empresa_id').val()
  tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({

    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: 'api/productos/todos/' + empresa,
      data: function (d) {
        d.codigo = $('input[name=consulta_producto_codigo]').val()
        d.linea = $('select[name=consulta_producto_linea]').val()
        d.seccion = $('select[name=consulta_producto_seccion]').val()
      }
    },
    columns: [
      {data: 'codigo', name: 'producto_nombre.codigo'},
      {data: 'descripcion', name: 'producto_nombre.descripcion'},
      {data: 'existencias', name: 'existencias'},
      {data: 'precio', name: 'precio'},
      {data: 'stock_minimo', name: 'stock_minimo'},
      {data: 'stock_maximo', name: 'stock_maximo'},
      {data: 'producto_nombre.linea.nombre', name: 'producto_nombre.linea.nombre'},
      {data: 'producto_nombre.seccion.nombre', name: 'producto_nombre.seccion.nombre'}
    ],

    'language':
      {
        'url':
          '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
      }
  })

})
```

The problem is that when im trying to search by codigo(code) it says that there isn't the column producto_nombre.codigo, I've replaced it with only codigo but also not working, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

`$empresa` is a single `Empresa` model instance.
`$productos` is an Eloquent collection of (assuming) `Producto` models with the two eager loaded relationships `producto_nombre` and `producto_nombre.seccion`. Any queries will there will be run on the (assuming) `productos` table instead of your relationship table.

Here's how to constrain eager loads: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads